# quick book payment integration

Tags: quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I am trying to integrate quick book to send and receive payments. But I don't find any api for payout(To send money to others). Also I don't find any api to get bank transactions associated with quick book. Client has quick book software but want to fetch transaction in other software. Any info regarding please let me know thanks.

Answer (score 1):

QuickBooks *does not have any APIs* to send payouts. This is *not something that QuickBooks / Intuit Payments supports*.

The `Intuit Payments` APIs for *taking payments* (*not* sending payouts) are documented here:

- https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbpayments/docs/api/resources/all-entities/bankaccounts